# Can I use a physical loop box with a phone-guitar interface?

Tags: electric-guitar

I sold my amp several years ago when moving, and I have been missing it more and more. I have never used one of these phone-guitar interfaces, but it seems very attractive to me to get fairly good sound effects from an application directly into my headphones.

I have a Boss RC-30 from my old band-playing days, and I love jamming with myself with that one. But can I use it normally with these interfaces? I imagine I could just connect it in-between the phone and my guitar, but would it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do that and it will work. If you can connect a regular guitar cable to it and it works as an amp simulator, then you can connect the looper to it as well and it will still work as an amp simulator.

Comment: The iRig HD2 fits your criteria, yes?

Comment: Can you connect a regular guitar cable to it, and it works as an amp simulator?

Comment: Not sure about "works as an amp simulator". It takes the signal from the guitar and passes it to, e.g., a phone. The amp simulation happens on the phone, right?

Comment: Amp simulator = takes guitar signal in, and makes it sound similar to how a real guitar amplifier would make it sound like.

Comment: Feel free to select either A or B. A): "I will not look up the iRig and answer your question." B) "I will look up the iRig and answer in a "Yes/No" fashion whether the iRig can be used with the Boss RC-30." I am fine with either, as long as you do one of them, and not what you are doing now.

Comment: @Yoda don't mark the answer as accepted if it's confused about what you're asking. Anyway, you can put the looper between guitar and interface, but there's no equivalent of FX loop. Amp simulation in phone is fine with iPhone, Androids have too much latency for that.

Comment: @ojs Please post your better answer, that's the whole purpose of this site. I answered the question completely, on the level of abstraction that I think is good. OP: please un-accept the answer, and wait for ojs's better one.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on what you mean by "normally". You can put effects between your guitar and the interface just like a real amp, but there is no equivalent of FX loop. Loopers are often used in FX loop, but if looper in front of amp is fine for you, it is possible.

On the other hand, most amp simulator apps do have a built-in looper. You will lose the footswitch, but otherwise you get all the functionality without the physical box.

As I already mentioned in a comment, you need an iOS phone for use with amp simulator app. Android phones just have too high latency to be usable.